# Only one Windows Software Development Kit installed at a time?

Tags: windows, ssd, visual-studio, sdk

I use an `SSD` so I don't have a lot of storage space but `Microsoft` always seems to install multiple `Windows Software Development Kit`s wasting tons of space:

[image]

And yes, I'm a software developer so I need an `SDK`. However, isn't there a way to only install the latest and keep the others off my PC? They silently install themselves without me noticing and suddenly my `C:` drive is full again.

Comment: Do you only have an SSD, or do you also have a 2nd drive? If its the latter, you can use mklink to move the installs. That way they are still installed, but won't consume disk space on your SSD anymore.

Comment: I have a `C:` and `D:` drive. Thanks for your suggestion, I will try it later.

Comment: Microsoft doesn't install it.  The Windows SDK is only installed by a user.  Can you modify the screenshot to indicate which versions are installed?  If you need multiple Windows SDK entirely depends on your developement needs